# Creating a repeating CSS Grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I've read through many other similar questions, and tried to do it myself for a few days, but I am stuck in creating a repeating CSS grid layout.

Right now I have succeeded in creating the layout as it should be, but it only works for up to 6 items. If any more are added they overlap with the current items as they are stuck in the same grid space. I would need the grid to be infinitely applicable for all the items that would follow underneath it. I have already tried working with :nth-child, both when defining *grid-template-areas* in the grid container, as well as using *grid-area*  on the individual items (as can be seen commented out below).

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
  "BigLeft BigLeft BigLeft SmallRight1 SmallRight1"
  "BigLeft BigLeft BigLeft SmallRight2 SmallRight2"
  "SmallLeft1 SmallLeft1 BigRight BigRight BigRight"
  "SmallLeft2 SmallLeft2 BigRight BigRight BigRight";
}

.item {
  background: #222;
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+1) {
  /* grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 4; */
  grid-area: BigLeft;
  min-height: 60vh;
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+2) {
  /* grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 6; */
  grid-area: SmallRight1;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+3) {
  /* grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 6; */
  grid-area: SmallRight2;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+4) {
  /* grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 3; */
  grid-area: SmallLeft1;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+5) {
  /* grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 3; */
  grid-area: SmallLeft2;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+6) {
  /* grid-area: 3 / 3 / 5 / 6; */
  grid-area: BigRight;
  min-height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

How can I repeat the (now 6-item) grid layout underneath the current grid, and allow this to work for as many items that may follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't define explicit area, only define the sizes and let the browser do the job for you

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 150px; /* height of one row */
}

.item {
  background: #222;
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+1),
.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+6){
  grid-area: span 2/span 3; /* take 2 rows and 3 columns */
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+2),
.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+3),
.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+4){
  grid-column: span 2; /* take 2 columns */
}

.grid-container > .item:nth-child(6n+5){
  grid-column: 1/span 2; /* take 2 columns and start at column 1*/
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why doesn't this amazing technique figure prominently in online grid CSS tutorials?  Bye bye table tags!

Comment: @AndyBrown I have one: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/